# Modify date in fluid's f:format.date - using inline notation

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

With the fluid `f:format.date` viewhelper, I can set an offset on a date:

```
<f:format.date format="%d.%m.%Y">{item.Date}-3 days</f:format.date>
```

Unfortunately, it's not that easy with the inline notation (which I need for a condition). I've tried the following with :

```
{f:format.date(date: item.Date-3 days, format: '%d.%m.%Y')}
{f:format.date(date: item.Date'-3 days', format: '%d.%m.%Y')}
{f:format.date(date: 'item.Date-3 days', format: '%d.%m.%Y')}
```

None of which returns a modified date.
What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we have {item.Date} as a DateTime object in our template, it will work by following ways:

```
<f:format.date format="d.m.Y">{item.Date->f:format.date(format: '%d.%m.%Y')}-3days</f:format.date>

{f:format.date(format: '%d.%m.%Y', date: '{item.Date->f:format.date(format: \'%d.%m.%Y\')}-3days')}
```

But in your case looks like {item.Date} is a simple string, in such case it will work by following way:

```
<f:format.date format="%d.%m.%Y">{item.Date}-3days</f:format.date>

{f:format.date(format: '%d.%m.%Y', date: '{item.Date}-3days')}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, {item.Date} is a Y-m-d date string, and your syntax works. Where could I have looked that up? I searched for "fluid date inline notation" and similar

Comment: This ist just regular inline notation.